# View mobile site link in full site

Tags: javascript, mobile, mobile-safari

While I have a successful method of getting users from our mobile site to our full site, I need help getting them from the full site back to the mobile site.

I'm trying to use a combination of CSS and Javscript-written HTML (below) which is using server side detection. Basically the detection determines if the user is on a smart phone and, if so, writes the banner HTML. [It should look like this](http://bit.ly/lAOIuO), but unfortunately this isn't working. PHP isn't an option.

My question is, how can I get the "View Mobile" banner to appear only on smart phones (i.e. iPhone & Android)?

[Here's my page](http://bit.ly/ilPPqN) and code:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mobile.css" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)" />
```

...

```
<body> 
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
device_class = readCookie('COOKIE_DEVICE_CLASS');
if (device_class == 'smart') {
document.write('<div id="view-mobile"><a href="http://m.stanford.edu/">View Stanford Mobile</a></div>');
}
// -->
</script>
```

Comment: have you tried getting the user agent? what do you mean php is not an option?

Comment: there is no cookie with value **COOKIE_DEVICE_CLASS** @AndrewR is correct I checked it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your cookie is not being set. I visited both stanford.edu and m.stanford.edu, and I do not get a COOKIE_DEVICE_CLASS cookie. If the cookie is created and contains 'smart' your code will work.

Comment: Thanks - didn't see that the cookie wasn't being created. Will use javascript detection until I can get the server to create the cookie.

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

```
var userAgent= navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();

if (!!/iphone/.test(userAgent) || !!/android/.test(userAgent)) {
    // write banner
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create htaccess on your mobile site then add this code.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !FULLSITE=yes
### Your current conditions...
RewriteRule (.*) http://your URL_mobile_add? [R,L]
```